# MySQL Match Relevance Score causes "DOUBLE value is out of range" error

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I created a MySQL (MariaDB) fulltext search in my Windows XAMPP environment. Everything works well. But when putting it on the live server (also using MariaDB), I get a 1690 Double value is out of range error from it with the exactly same data.

I assume that the problem is somewhere in the MariaDB settings. I just cannot figure out, which setting this could be.

Here is the query simplified:

`SELECT id, (MATCH (name) AGAINST ('"exactSearchPhrase"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)*3 + MATCH (name) AGAINST ('single*, Words*, Search*, Phrase*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) as relevance, name FROM tableName WHERE MATCH(name) AGAINST('search Phrase' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ORDER BY relevance DESC`

And this is the error I get

> Numeric value out of range: 1690 DOUBLE value is out of range in '(match `name` against ('"exactSearchPhrase"' in boolean mode)) * 3

Does anyone have an idea which setting could cause this behaviour that might be different from the one in my standard Xampp environment?

**Edit after some Try and Error:**
Any kind of operation with the match result causes this error. This confuses me even more:

**No error:**
`SELECT id, (MATCH (name) AGAINST ('"exactSearchPhrase"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) as relevance, name FROM tableName WHERE MATCH(name) AGAINST('search Phrase' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ORDER BY relevance DESC`

**Error:**
`SELECT id, (MATCH (name) AGAINST ('"exactSearchPhrase"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)+0) as relevance, name FROM tableName WHERE MATCH(name) AGAINST('search Phrase' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ORDER BY relevance DESC`

**Edit:**
I ended up building the whole table again. It seemed to be a problem with the fulltext index itself.

Comment: can you please add some data, where you get the error https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5b7d7d2d7f2a94206c0508ff771a0430

Comment: thank you for trying to help. What data do you need? The exact search phrase? I am not sure, what I should enter to give you more information. The error seems to happen in the first part of the query with the multiplier (*3). Somehow the relevance score seems to be out of the "double" range.

Comment: try to replicate the error in the fiddle.

Comment: Try selecting just `MATCH (name) AGAINST ('"exactSearchPhrase"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)`, and then a separate query to select just `MATCH (name) AGAINST ('single*, Words*, Search*, Phrase*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)`, to determine which of those generates a large DOUBLE value. Chances are the problem is the former.

Comment: First part without multiplier has a relevance of 1.78...e308, second part is 1.79...e308

Comment: Strange thing. I just tested the query like this    `SELECT id, (MATCH (name) AGAINST ('"exactSearchPhrase"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) as relevance, name FROM tableName WHERE MATCH(name) AGAINST('search Phrase' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ORDER BY relevance DESC` with no errors, but this same query here causes rthe error as described above:  `SELECT id, (MATCH (name) AGAINST ('"exactSearchPhrase"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)*1) as relevance, name FROM tableName WHERE MATCH(name) AGAINST('search Phrase' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ORDER BY relevance DESC`  (notice the *1).

Comment: I asume it must be some kind of setting of the database that limits the possible value of double when processing calculations in the background. But which setting could this be?

Comment: Same problem on production. Its make on column where is only value what Im searching.
Did you solve somehow?

Comment: @Mr. RJ it turned out to be an error in the fulltext index. I ended up creating the whole table again to build a new index. See Liams answer below, it might help you, since it addresses the same problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `ANALYZE TABLE table_name`. It worked for me.

I recently encountered the same issue with a DigitalOcean Managed Database, after a MySQL upgrade, which I believe involved switching over to a replica.  I got the same error message "DOUBLE value is out of range" when I multiplied the relevance score by any number, including `* 1`. And the query succeeded when I ran it without the multiplication.

The relevance score seemed incorrect to me, judging by comparing the example in the MySQL docs to a similar search in my data. So I assumed that something was wrong with the FULLTEXT index, and ran `ANALYZE TABLE`, and then it worked correctly again.

I don't know the exact cause of the problem, but I do note the similarity of switching servers in my case and in the OP's case.